# Controller not getting invoked from Ajax URL?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

Ajax Function below which should call the Controller class. Controller not getting invoked. Only 1st alert within generateExcel getting printed.

```
function generateExcel(bIndex){
  alert("Inside generateExcel of export_path -> branchIndex = "+bIndex);

  $.ajax({
    type:"post",
    url:"generate/exportexcel.do?branchIndex="+bIndex,
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(data){
      alert("Inside export_path generateExcel()"+data.length);
    }
  });
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/generate/exportexcel.do")
public String docGeneration(String branchIndex) { 

    System.out.println("branchIndex ==> " +branchIndex);
     try{
        DocGenerator.generateExcel(branchIndex, order, filename, categoryDao);
     }
     catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
    return "message/result";
 }
```

Comment: check your browser console for any errors

Comment: controller action may be cached

Comment: cleared the cache and also found no errors on the console.

Comment: Have you tried accessing your controller via browser directly?

Answer (score 0):

If you have written code like

```
  <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

in web.xml

then i think there is no need to write `.do` in following line ..

```
@RequestMapping("/generate/exportexcel.do")
```

therefore change it to

```
@RequestMapping("/generate/exportexcel")
```

If this is not the answer then show your `web.xml` file's `servlet-mapping` entry

Comment: Hey.. is it working? if not can you please show your web.xml file's servlet-mapping entry